# How to force reload routes in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a script that dynamically update existing routes then dump those routes to a cache file within the same request for later use.

I was able to figure out the way to delete all current route cache files, then use warmUp on the router, but when I use getRouteCollection I will still get the same old routes within that request since the collection is already loaded. When I try to force reload the collection by using a custom router and fource collection to null, I get the error

> Do Not Add The "abc_custom" Loader Twice In ....

My guess is that the loader seems to reload all configs files (not limited to routing config files) and that causes the error.

I wonder if I'm taking the wrong approach to this issue or if there is any good way to get around this?

Comment: Redirecting would do it but your approach is a bit fragile.  If another request comes in while you are fooling around with the cache then it might fail.  There are several approaches to dynamic routing.  Consider researching them.

Comment: You are right about it being fragile, but if I generate the cache in an alternative folder then copy them over then it's basically the same as clearing cache of the application and can minimize the risk? I looked into DynamicRouter but it seems like an overkill since I do not need all that power (which come with its performance penalty). I'm looking into its code to see how it handles new route adding to the collection however, hopefully it can give some hints.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, in the end I ended up manually clearing the route cache folder (this was for SF3). I have just upgraded to SF4 and will need to update my code because they seem to have updated the way they generate route cache folder in SF4.